# PHP Mysql Poor performance when Using Key Exists

Tags: php

I am having problems with poor performance regarding the time taken to retrieve records using PHP that uses OO techniques.

This is the code that returns the row from MySQL, instantiates and make sure the attributes exist

```
 public function find_by_sql($sql="") {
            global $database;
            $result_set = $database->query($sql);
            //we can use this later
            $this->sql = $sql;
            $object_array = array();
            while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result_set)) {
              $object_array[] = static::instantiate($row);
            }
            return $object_array;
     }

    private static function instantiate($record) {
            // Could check that $record exists and is an array
            $class_name = get_called_class();
            $object = new $class_name;
            foreach($record as $attribute=>$value){
              if($object->has_attribute($attribute)) {
                $object->$attribute = $value;
              }
            }
            return $object;
    }
    private function has_attribute($attribute) {
          // We don't care about the value, we just want to know if the key exists
          // Will return true or false
          return array_key_exists($attribute, $this->attributes());
    }

          protected function attributes() { 
                // return an array of attribute names and their values
              $attributes = array();
              foreach(static::$db_fields  as $field) {
                if(property_exists($this, $field)) {
                  $attributes[$field] = $this->$field;
                }
              }
              return $attributes;
        }
```

db_fields  array have been defined elsewhere e.g

```
protected static $db_fields = array('car_id', 'make', 'model', 'reg')
```

I have tracked the bottleneck to the function where a check is done to see if the key exists. I commented out the code below and the performance is 100% improved:

```
    private static function instantiate($record) {
            // Could check that $record exists and is an array
            $class_name = get_called_class();
             $object = new $class_name;
            foreach($record as $attribute=>$value){
               ///if($object->has_attribute($attribute)) {
                $object->$attribute = $value;
             /// }
            }
            return $object;
    }
```

To give you an idea on the affect using the function has regarding performance, it takes 6 seconds longer when it is called.

Can anyone advise me on the impact of not using the function and if there is a way I can keep it but increase performance.

I understand that array_key_exists() is used  to see if the columns returned in the query  are in the attribute array $this->attributes() which is initially declared in the $db_fields.

I checked the $this->attributes() array which  printed the following

array(3) { ["car_id"]=> NULL ["make"]=> NULL ["model"]=>  ["reg"]=> NULL}

isset () is an alternative to array_key_exists() but cant be used because although the key exists it is false as the value is null.  Which brings me back to a work around not to use the function array_key_exists() because of its slow performance

Comment: Also, what is `$this->attributes()`?

Comment: I have added now edited the question and added that part bit of code

Comment: A bottleneck with `array_key_exists()` is very suspect, even with hundreds of fields, I wouldn't expect such slow performance. You are refilling that `$attributes` array each time the `attributes()` method is called. Perhaps you should cache the result, like `if (empty($this->attributes)) {foreach (static::$db_fields as $field)....}`  wherein `$this->attributes` becomes an object property instead of a local array variable.

Comment: i tried that but didn't make any difference, I then used if (!array_filter($this->attributes)) { and got an error saying a value wasn't given, so probably means $this->attributes isn't an array

Comment: @Michael Berkowski, to test your theory further, I replicated the array I defined for the database columns in the "has_attribute" method,and used that to stop the need of calling the attributes method, this reduced the loading time by over a half, therefor you were correct.  I just need to stop re-building the attribute array

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment by Michael Berkowski I narrowed the problem down to the constant calls to the method attributes() from the has_attributes method. Although there are probably more refined ways to do this I added this to the has_attribute method

```
        private function has_attribute($attribute) {
            ///if this is the first call attr_array will be empty so we will populate it by calling attributes method
              if (empty($this->attr_array)) { 
                  $this->attr_array = $this->attributes();
              } 
              ///either way, at this point attr_array is populated 
              return array_key_exists($attribute, $this->attr_array);
        }
```

This has reduced the loading time of the page by 70%

Comment: I'm glad you sorted it out. I'm surprised filling that array many times caused that much of a performance degradation, but then I don't know just how many times`attributes()` was being called.. Such a severe hit is more often the result of a bad SQL query.

Comment: Though it was noticeably slow on all  classes that I have for my tables one particular class was retrieving approx 25 columns, from a table of 3000 records, with a limit of 20. This was taking approximately 10 seconds. I have fast internet and the web app is on its own VPS. It now takes approx 2 seconds.  I was convinced form what I had read it was the array_key_exists function, your suggestion highlighted a potential cause I hadn't considered